# Почему не отображается Title в Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

Есть Toolbar не могу понять почему в нем не отображается Title, в чем может быть причина?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/rvBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        android:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

в onCreate:

```
 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.rvBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: android:titleTextColor="@color/white" работает только на level api >= 23 ,  может поэтому

Comment: @KirillStoianov Оу, а что использовать для api <23?

Comment: @Lucky_girl, стили)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб А что нужно поменять в стилях, что б установить цвет Title в   toolbar?

Comment: @Lucky_girl пишут что  можно так app:titleTextColor="@color/primary_text" но у меня почему то не сработало. вот глянь тут может поможет http://stackoverflow.com/q/26852108/5634351

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        ....
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarColor"
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Style:

```
<style name="ToolbarColor" parent="AppTheme">
     <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
     <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```